# Netlogo not writing results to file correctly

Tags: netlogo

I’m running simulations in Netlogo, with coding to send results automatically to a spreadsheet. This occurs at the end of a simulation in order to save each individual’s variables (e.g., identity, home range size, etc.). The spreadsheet results look fine normally, but when using BehaviorSpace, occasionally data from an individual's variables are not printed correctly (e.g., data in wrong columns or missing, see screenshot below).

I’m wondering if during parallel runs in BehaviorSpace, when simulations happen to end at the same time this results in simultaneous writing to the file. Is that likely what’s happening? Should I be reasonably confident that remaining results were printed correctly to the table, aside from these noticeable issues? Most importantly, how can I avoid these misprints to the file? Sample code follows.

Bonus question [SOLVED]: I thought printing date-and-time would identify unique simulation runs, but this is not the case since each turtle's variables take more than an instant to print to the file. Is there a quick way to add a unique identifier for each simulation run?

Thanks!

```
to start-output-file ;; Observer procedure, called from setup. 
  set-current-directory "C:\\... 
  file-open "Table_results.csv"
  ;; Define the names of the variables:
     file-type "Run,"
     file-type "Landscape,"
     file-type "Individual,"
     file-type "Home range size,"
     ;; ... and so on, ~60 results saved for each individual            
     file-print ""
     file-close ]
end

to end-simulation ;; Observer procedure, called from go.
  write-outputs
  file-close 
end

to write-outputs ;; Observer procedure, called from end-simulation.
  set-current-directory "C:\\...
  file-open "Table_results.csv"
  ask turtles
    [ file-type (word date-and-time ", ") ;;<---Would like a unique run identifier here instead if possible.
      file-type (word Landscape ", ")
      file-type (word Who ", ")
      file-type (word Home-range-size ", ")
      ;; ...
      file-print "" ]]    
end
```

[image]

Comment: You said you are using BehaviorSpace; why not let it format your output for you?  Or at least use the `csv` extension.
You can uniquely identify the run with `behaviorspace-run-number`.

Comment: I believe BehaviorSpace will only provide outputs summarized across all individuals (such as means), not information for each individual. If incorrect, how can one save each individual's variables in BehaviorSpace?

Comment: You can report anything you want in BehaviorSpace, but of course there are constraints.  E.g., the easiest way here would be to put a list of attribute values in a single cell and process it afterwards.  If that seems too awkward, there is still the CSV extension.  Finally, if you really want your current approach, examine the CSV file with a text editor to see what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update/Solution:** My solution was to have each model run write to a separate CSV. This allowed me to save results of each agent's variables. Files will each have a unique identifier so won't get overwritten or added to later. All the CSVs can then easily be imported and combined using Program R.

**Example Code:** Define a CSV file name during setup, and ask turtles to write their results to the file:

```
extensions [ csv ]
globals [ filename ] ;; Will define as the date/time and BehaviorSpace run #.

to setup
  clear-all 
  let run-ID (remove-item 6 (remove-item 7 (remove-item 8 (remove "-"(remove " "(remove "." (remove ":" date-and-time)))))))
  set filename (word "Results, " run-ID ", " word behaviorspace-run-number".csv")
  file-open filename
  start-output-file
  ;; Etc.
end

to start-output-file ;; Called from setup.
   file-open filename
   file-type "Turtle identity,"
   file-type "Home range size,"
   ;; Etc., rest of column headers.
   file-print ""
end

to end-simulation ;; Observer procedure, called from go.
  ask turtles [ write-outputs ]
  file-close 
end

to write-outputs ;; Called from end-simulation.
  file-type (word Who ", ") 
  file-type (word home-range-size ", ") ;; (Turtle variable for home range size.)
  ;; Etc., i.e., each turtle variable you are writing to file.
  file-print ""
end
```

Hope this helps someone else looking to do something similar, or noticing similar oddities in their CSV output from BehaviorSpace.